# Error 1075 Mysql Mariadb

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, tablas

Estoy creando una tabla en **Mysql** sin embargo por alguna razón me arroja el **error 1075**.

A continuación les muestro el código de la tabla junto al error:

```
MariaDB [Juan]> CREATE TABLE persona (
    -> id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> nombres VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    -> apellidos VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    -> email VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    -> edad INT,
    -> website VARCHAR(128),
    -> estado ENUM('activo', 'inactivo') DEFAULT 'inactivo',
    -> pais INT NOT NULL,
    -> PRIMARY KEY (estado)
    -> );
ERROR 1075 (42000): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Como el mismo mensaje lo indica: *Solo puedes emplear el  `AUTO_INCREMENT` en la misma columna que defines como llave primaria*, realiza ese cambio y se soluciona

Answer (score 0):

por lo que pude ver en tu codigo, el error viene dado que tienes el id definido como autoincremental pero no lo reflejas como una clave primaria.

espero te pueda ayudar

Answer (score 0):

tienes que reflejar el auto `increment` como llave primaria seria:

```
primary key(id, estado)
```